# How to understand "it is follow from..., however,...." in this sentence

Tags: sentence

The whole sentence is "It does not follow from their lack of speech, however, that chimpanzees are incapable of language".

Is it possible to rephrase this sentence so it's easy to understand?
Article from this website:https://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/ling002.html

Comment: Hi Jennifer, welcome to EL&U.  What is it about the sentence that you don't understand? Did you look up "follow" in a dictionary? Regrettably, I'm flagging this question for closure: proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Is there a better way to write this passage?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. For further guidance, see [ask]. :-)

Comment: Does this help? "However, it does not follow from their lack of speech that chimpanzees are incapable of language."

Comment: The sentence in your question title does not match the sentence in your question text. "It is follow" is not the same as "It does not follow".

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, it means:

> Just because chimpanzees don't *talk* doesn't mean they don't understand what we say or can't communicate in other ways.

Language isn't something that has to be verbal. Many people use sign language, for instance. Even people who do speak also communicate non-verbally through gestures. And just because you don't respond to somebody, that doesn't mean you don't understand them.

In fact, chimpanzees *are* capable of communicating through sign language. An example is [Washoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washoe_(chimpanzee)).